# ¿Cómo puedo incluir un ScrollView dentro de un componente Touchable?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tengo un componente principal `View` que contiene otro componente `ScrollView`, que es un carrusel de imágenes, y otro `View` que incluye un componente `Text`. Quiero poder hacer touch sobre el `View` principal y abrir otra vista de la app, pero también necesito hacer scroll de las imágenes en el carrusel.

Intenté poner el `View` principal dentro de un `TouchableOpacity` (también lo intenté con `TouchableHighlight` y `TouchableWithoutFeedback`) y no funciona bien.

El código siguiente es la aproximación que he seguido para intentar resolver el problema:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showView}>
  <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <Image
          key={index}
          styleName={styleName}
          source={image}
        />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.title}>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        <Text>{sample text}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Jorge. Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial del sitio es el español por lo que has de traducir la pregunta. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Perdona, ya he traducido la pregunta. Muchas gracias